# React useEffect inifinite loop onchange method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have create a component:

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState({street: 'via roma', number: 2})

const onChangeAddress = (newAddress) => {
    setAddress(newAddress)
}

<Address initialAddress={address} onChange={onChangeAddress}/>
```

detail of Address component:

```
const Address = (props) => {
    const {address, onChange} = props
    const [addressLocation, setAddressLocation] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setAddressLocation(address)
    }, [address])

    const onChangeStreet = (event: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void => {
        setAddressLocation(previousState => ({ ...previousState, street: event.target.value }))
    }

    const onChangeNumber = (event: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void => {
        setAddressLocation(previousState => ({ ...previousState, number: event.target.value }))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(addressLocation)
    }, [addressLocation])

    return <div>
        <input value={addressLocation.street} onChange={onChangeStreet} />
        <input value={addressLocation.number} onChange={onChangeNumber} />
    </div>
}
```

Why receveive this error 'Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render' ?

what is the procedure for creating a method of changing the value and initializing the inputs?

Comment: The 2 different `useEffect`s are triggering/invoking each other on-a-loop, I think. The first one takes the `address` from the prop and updates it to the state. This triggers the second `useEffect` because now the state `addressLocation` got changed. Add a condition something like: `if (addressLocation !== address)` to prevent this.

Comment: Yes this will cause an infine loop, because your depency array includes
    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(addressLocation)
    }, [addressLocation])
address location, and you are calling onChange there, which is changing the addressLocation object again, and as a result you end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating addressLocation whenever addressLocation change, causing a infinite loop

```
   useEffect(() => {
        onChange(addressLocation) //u call the onchange props
    }, [addressLocation])



 useEffect(() => {
        setAddressLocation(address) // you are updating the addressLocation again
    }, [address]) //ur onchange props change the props.address
```

You should probably call this only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAddressLocation(address)
}, [])
```

Or don't use `props.onChange` at all.

Comment: ok, how can i get the new address item to come back?

Comment: Either manage your state within your component, or manage the state from parent component, not both.

Comment: I think, you can stick to using just one: either the `props` or the `state`, based on your requirement. It will change in either case.

Comment: can't figure out how to return the updated item to the father?

Comment: when you called `props.onChange`, you are already calling a parent function. e.g. `<Address initialAddress={address} onChange={onChangeAddress}/>`